# jQuery: selector parsing mechanism

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

From doc:

`$(selector, context)` internally implements the `.find()` method.

But when we write some selector like;

`$('#a .b .c')`

or

`$('#a > .b > .c')`

etc.

Does this implement `.find()` method? or something else mechanism jQuery used for this.

Please make me clear about this parsing mechanism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modern implementations will hand the selector over to `document.querySelectorAll()` where the browser will attempt to parse it as a CSS selector (assuming it is valid).

Failing that, jQuery falls back to its own selector engine, [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com), which uses internal methods and calculations to traverse the DOM when implementing the descendant and sibling selectors, which most likely *don't* employ methods like `.find()` as that would incur unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Thanks Sir, that means it does not always use `find()` method, right?